# How to change the the opacity of this Bootstrap 4 card without affecting on the form and buttons inside it?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use this Bootstrap 4 login form.

https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/login/

I am trying to figure out how to solve these 2 troubles.

1. I am trying to change the opacity of .card-signin but when I change it affects the form and buttons as well. How can I change opacity only for the card, not for the elements inside it?
2. How can I center this card in the middle of the screen vertically? It shows in the top while I tried different combinations with vertical-align?

Answer (score 2):

Add below css and you're all set...

```
html,body,.container,.row {
    height: 100%;
}
.col-sm-9.col-md-7.col-lg-5.mx-auto {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
.card.card-signin.my-5 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. according to content alignment? Is it changing general classes of Bootstrap or it changes only this form's row and col? I am asking it because it might affect all elements which use those general classes.

Comment: Just add some custom classes to above elements if it affects other elements.

Comment: Nice answer @BuggyParadox

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Hehe, thanks. We kids are learning in your guidance. Hope you got the email. :)

Comment: Thanks, it works, however after making some fixes it bring back another trouble:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819503/when-i-try-to-use-container-fluid-centered-form-is-moving-to-the-left-how-to-ke

Answer (score 1):

"*How can I center this card in the middle of the screen vertically? It shows in the top while I tried different combinations with vertical-align?*"
Important! Vertical center is relative to the height of the parent

If the parent of the element your trying to center has no defined height, none of the vertical centering solutions will work!

Now, onto vertical centering in Bootstrap 4...

You can use the new flexbox & size utilities to make the container full-height and display: flex. These options don't require extra CSS (except that the height of the container (ie:html,body) must be 100%).

**Option 1 align-self-center on flexbox child**

```
<div class="container d-flex h-100">
<div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
 I'm vertically centered
</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://www.codeply.com/go/fFqaDe5Oey)

**Option 2 align-items-center on flexbox parent (.row is display:flex; flex-direction:row)**

```
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            I'm vertically centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://www.codeply.com/go/BumdFnmLuk)

**Option 3 justify-content-center on flexbox parent (.card is display:flex;flex-direction:column)**

```
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card h-100 border-primary justify-content-center">
            <div>
                ...card content...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://www.codeply.com/go/3gySSEe7nd)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using opacity, you can try out following style.

```
.card-body {
    background: rgba(255, 252, 252, 0.09);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below css.

```
.card {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2) !important;
}
```